# Настройка шаблона писем woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Добрый день. Хочу добавить поле "Категория" рядом с наименованием товара (в шаблоне письма который приходит на почту при заказе). Сделать как на скриншоте.  Подскажите пожалуйста как это реализовать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Эта таблица формируется в файлах

`wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/emails/email-order-details.php` и

`wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/emails/email-order-‌​items.php`.

Вам нужно скопировать эти файлы в папку `/woocommerce/emails/` вашей темы (если ее нет, то создать) и отредактировать их, вставив туда свои данные.

Comment: Я добавил заголовки таблицы <th class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:left;">Категория</th>, а как добавить теперь содержимое (категории)?

Comment: Вам надо править файл `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/emails/email-order-items.php` (скопировав в свою папку)

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Comment: @KAGGDesign при случае попробуй сделать задачу ТСа. Ну и вообще изменить формирование письма - удалить/добавить/ поменять местами  данные, применить html-форматирование к разным участкам, привести таблицу в др вид и всё тому подобно,. Это не так просто как кажется на первый взгляд (я с кандачка не взял этот барьер, а потом уже и не нужно было). Если будет желание и получится разобраться -  и я  был бы безмерно благодарен за небольшой ман. Не теоретические выкладки, а практический результат.

Comment: @SeVlad я правил формы отправки, и успешно

Comment: Да я тоже правил, но легко - возможно по мелочи. Чтобы управлять отдельными данными в таблице - надо ковырять АПИ. Вот хоть задача ТС может и кажется мелочью, но не всё так просто. Но если ты более серьёзное что-то делал и знаешь - ну расскажи плз как-нибудь.. Ну когда будет настроение и желание написать небольшое "практическое пособие", как ты это делал уже не раз на SO :)

Comment: @SeVlad идея хорошая, найти бы время )

Comment: Разобрался, нужно вставить в email-order-‌​items.php: <td><?php echo $_product->get_categories(); ?></td>  и отобразятся категории.